# limit points, metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Generalised edit:
what can we say about set of limit points that are not in the set itself and about limit points that are in the set individually?

Comment: Not closed does not imply open.

Comment: edited, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

For the set of all rational numbers in the real line with the standard metric the set of limit points not in the set is the set of irrationals numbers which is neither open nor closed.